# How to help them succeed

Tags: infinitives

why the following question is-> ***How to help them succeed?*** instead of **How to help them** **TO** **succeed**?

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct.  However, "how to help them succeed" doesn't repeat the word "to" and may sound better.

Answer (score 0):

The preposition "to" signifies orientation toward a goal. [1](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/594/02/)

When the goal is an action, "to" marks a verb; it is attached as an infinitive and expresses purpose.

Comment: Took the words right out of my mouth! (good answer, mate)

Comment: Thank you @DieterSchmidtJohann.  But apparently a coward down voted your up vote without leaving a reason. Such petty people.

Comment: Indeed. Such petty people.